# To get records in comma seperated List LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, csv

I have a table in database called **Products** and which has a column name called **LaunchYear**(int) data type.I want to filter the table using a CSV list of Launch Years.

```
listCSVLaunchYear= "5,7,8";
```

I want help to create a LINQ to Entity query which will return me all products in CSV list. I tried using contains but that did not work. Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to convert the CSV list to underlying column data type list and then use `Contains`, like this

```
var launchYears = listCSVLaunchYear.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
var query = db.Products.Where(p => launchYears.Contains(p.LaunchYear));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question, but I was able to resolve it by my own using a strongly types list for launchYears. Your solution also works fine but now I have another problem with another column called approvedState which contains vales in database like : "AL,AK,AR"  etc and the listCSVState='AL,AK'. Can you please help me to resolve this

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll get help, from me or someone else. But by the rules of this site, it's a different issue, so please post another question.

Comment: Thanks for information. Let me put another question